# Google font src url in SVG

Tags: svg, google-fonts

I am running into a parsing error when adding google font url to an SVG.

The font is 'NunitoSans-Regular' and the url I am using is:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap');
```

Here is the relevent SVG markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 376 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 376 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap');
    .st0{fill:#EFC7C7;}
    .st1{fill:#90EEE1;}
    .st2{fill:#F15641;}
    .st3{display:none;}
    .st4{display:inline;}
    .st5{font-family:'NunitoSans-Regular';}
    .st6{font-size:45px;}
</style>
```

The browser returns this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standalone SVG files are parsed not by a (forgiving) HTML parser, but the XML parser. (That, by the way, is independent of whether you quote the XML prolog as the first line or not.) The latter is much more restrictive in what it considers "well-formed". In your case, it expects the `&` to be the start of an [entity reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

You can avoid this error by escaping the content of the `<style>` element as a [CDATA section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 376 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 376 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap');
    .st0{fill:#EFC7C7;}
    .st1{fill:#90EEE1;}
    .st2{fill:#F15641;}
    .st3{display:none;}
    .st4{display:inline;}
    .st5{font-family:'Nunito Sans';}
    .st6{font-size:45px;}
]]></style>

</svg>
```

Note that you must the correct `font-family` name: If your request says `family=Nunito+Sans`, the font will only be used if it is used with `font-family: 'Nunito Sans'`.

Comment: So, this worked partially. The parsing error is gone but the text is loaded in Times New Roman.